# Magento disable search bar only in hompage

Tags: css, magento, search

Today we decided to remove the search bar from the Home page of our website. But the only thing is that we don't know how to do this.

We have been going through a lot of forums but apparently it doesn't fix our problem.
So our question states: How do you remove the search bar for only the Home page?

As an end result, we want that you can't search the store without being logged in.

We have already successfully disabled the search bar on the whole website using CSS. But that's not what we wanted.

Comment: Well, you should be atleast aware of basics. We(_most of_) can't explain you the problem step by step. I suggest you to read some blogs to gain knowledge about magento and then post the code which you have tried. If you already know magento then please post the code which you have tried with explanation of what is not working exactly.

Comment: I didnt worked with magento, but worked with joomla. can u clarify the doubt. Is there any option found 'module suffix class' in menu create option in admin panel?

Comment: @Mr_Green we have added `.form-search {display: none;}` to the styles.css file. that did remove the serach bar but i removed it from all the pages. is there a way to give the homepage a different stylesheet?

Comment: @djeroen yes you need to change the search bar related template. which will be of file type `.phtml`.

Comment: @Mr_Green is it correct that you are talking about the header.phtml?

Comment: @djeroen currently, I am on my home pc. So, I don't have magento to refer. but as far as I remember, it should be in `form.mini.phtml` template file of your **theme** package. Can be found in `{theme}/template/catalogsearch/form.mini.phtml`.

Comment: @Mr_Green Okay I have found the `form.mini.phtml`, now is there a way to detect if a user is logged in?

Comment: @djeroen there are many links which explains the same. Here is one [**link**](http://www.jnorton.co.uk/blog/magento-check-if-customer-logged) which I found in quick google search. BTW, I would suggest you to let user (_even guest_) use search but when he/she is not logged in, the page will redirect to login page. or if the user is already logged in, then the search will work as usual.

Comment: @Mr_Green We have the same thoughts, but our boss doesn't. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @djeroen haha.. ok good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

Hi @Mr_Green how are you?, you can remove the search bar very easy from the home page.
You just need to go to the CMS page assigned to be the home page the go to Design tab then Layout Update XML. Add this line to the end of the contet

```
<remove name="top.search"/>
```

I don't understand the other part of the question about the show to search bar if the customer is not log in. If you need this, you can add a local.xml to you theme folder > layout. Then you can use a  functionality under the xml logic. If is that what do you want I can explain in other post.

Best,
GriGo.

Comment: Well I double check before in a test site I had installed... My magento instance is a native one, I'm not sure if you change something.
If you want we can use the other solution to create a local.xml under your theme/layout folder and reference cms_index_index and remove the top.search